# Can we use zulu jdk 1.8 on our production systems for free?

Tags: java, azul-zulu, corretto

Oracle will require commercial licensing for Java 8 updates from Jan 2019. Currently we are using oracle jdk and we want to switch to amazon corretto JDK. 
However Amazon Corretto is not available for Centos 7. We are planning to use Zulu JDK as it gives frequent software updates. Do we have to pay for using Zulu JDK? Suggest me some options for which JDK I can freely use until Amazon release Corretto .

Comment: This is more of an AWS support question than a technical programming problem. Not appropriate to Stack Overflow. Seek support from Amazon, or use a discussion site such as http://www.JavaRanch.com/

Comment: Both suggestions and licensing questions are off-topic for stack overflow

Comment: CentOS comes with OpenJDK 1.8 that's based on the version in RHEL. The version of OpenJDK in RHEL is supported by Red Hat: https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/history-and-future-openjdk. Given that it's a part of CentOS packages, you should absolutely be able to use it for free. And if you want to pay for support, switching from CentOS to RHEL should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: @GlobeAdmin any OpenJDK are technically safe to use or redistribute with your application for free. OpenJDK is released under the GPL 2.0 with Assembly Exception and not a "bare" GPL. This is in addition to the Classpath exception to the GPL that applies mostly to the runtime library code. Please take note that I'm not a lawyer. If you're not limited in budget, it's always best to pay support to company like Azul to support the OpenJDK community

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are various OpenJDK builds out there, with various degrees of testing, platform support, and a history of regular availability. Of these Zulu is probably the regularly available OpenJDK build that is well tested and readily available for the most platforms, and is backed by the largest JVM engineering team outside than Oracle’s. Zulu is available for pretty much any Linux distro (including Alpine), as well as Windows, MacOS, and ARM 64/32.

You don’t have to pay to use Zulu. It is free to download and use, and is 100% OSS. There are paid options (Zulu Enterprise, Zulu embedded) that add support and update SLAs, support for various embedded environments, and other considerations that are important to companies that redistribute JDKs in various forms (in devices, with their software, on the cloud, etc.), like non-contamination analysis and certification.

Answer (score 3):

For now you can use the AL2 RPM on CentOS. If you find any issues please let us know